# Django: assertEqual(response.status_code, 200): I want to see useful stack of functions calls

Tags: python, django, django-testing

If I use the django testing web client like this, I get a useless traceback.

Here is example code which looks very similar to my testing code:

```
def test_details(self):
        # Issue a GET request.
        response = self.client.get('/customer/details/')

        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#example

Output, if I run `py.test -k test_bar` (same via PyCharm)

```
___________________________________________ Check.test_bar ___________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo_egs_d/src/foo-abc/foo_abc/tests/test_abc.py", line 321, in test_bar
    self.assertEqual(404, response.status_code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 513, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 506, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

The traceback is useless for me, since I see the traceback of the `assertEqual()` method.

A useful traceback for me in this context would show me the traceback where the Response with the unexpected status_code was created.

Since there is no exception when the wrong response gets created, the term "traceback" does not match. I want to see the stack(trace) of this moment.

I guess something like this should be possible. For example django debug toolbar can show every stacktrace of every ORM-SQL command that gets executed. I ask myself how this gets done ...

How could this be done?

My intention: I want to see more useful information immediately if the test fails.

## Bounty

There is already a working answer, but may be there is a better solution.

Comment: You shouldn't see any traceback at all here. What do you see, and what do you want to see?

Comment: have you inherited the class from `unittest.TestCase` ?

Comment: @KarthikRavindra yes, I use `unittest.TestCase` and not from django's TestCase.

Comment: This is not a traceback of the function call. it is an assertion error. You are expecting a 200, but receiving a 404. Fix that, and your issue will be resolved

Comment: @KarthikRavindra yes, I want to fix this. But I want to fix this as fast as possible without long debugging. I want to see where traceback where the wrong Response was created. This gives me much useful information. Up to now I don't see more than "200 != 404".

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why should I see no traceback? I know, there is something wrong in my code. That's ok. I just want to see more useful information immediately.

Comment: No offense, but what is the point in trying to fix something if you really dont understand what is going on ? Clearly, your issue is `/customer/details/` is resolving to 404. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820137/django-testing-see-traceback-where-wrong-response-gets-created)

Comment: You won't get the traceback you want because there's no exception on your view code. Returning 404 isn't a exception and thus there's not an exception to look at. You're getting an exception on your test case, because that's where the exception is: you're doing an assert(200 == 404), which blows up as an `AssertionError`.

Comment: @Tiago yes, you are right. I was mixing up two different but at first sight equal looking terms: "traceback" and "stack". Yes, there is not Exception in the moment where the wrong Response gets created. But still I would like to see the stacktrace of this moment. Like django-debug-toolbar can show me every stacktrace of each SQL statement.